# Induced chart on tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-spaces

I have the following statement in my lecture:

Let $(M,g)$ be Riemannian manifold, $(U, \varphi)$ local chart on $U \subset M$, $\varphi=(x^1,...,x^n)$ and projection $\pi:TM \rightarrow M$. Then we have an induced chart

$(\pi^{-1}(U), \varphi_{*})$, where $\varphi_{*}=(x^1,...,x^n,y^1,...,y^n)$.

Now I don't know what the $y^i$ are supposed to be.

My interpretation is:

You can see $v \in TM$ as a pair $(p,v)$, if $v \in T_pM$. Then $\varphi_{*}((p,v))=(\varphi(p), v(x^1),...,v(x^n))$

Is that correct?

Comment: Don't you mean $\pi:TM\to M$?

Comment: Oh yes, of course, thanks, I'll correct it

Answer (score 2):

If you mean $v(x_i)$ as the tangent vector $v$ applied to the function $x_i$, then yes, you are correct.

Equivalently, this is the same thing as saying that a vector $v\in T_pM$ given in these coordinates by $(\varphi (p),y^1(p,v),\ldots,y^n(p,v))$ is the tangent vector

$$v=\sum_{i=1}^ny^i(p,v)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)_p$$

so you probably start using these coordinates without even thinking about it as soon as you prove that $T_pM$ is a vector space and that the $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)_p$'s form a basis.

To make it more clear as to why that statement actually means this, you have to know that $\varphi_*$ means the push-forward $TM\to T\mathbb{R}^n\cong\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. And the way this push-forward (or the push-forward of any other differentiable function between differentiable manifolds, for that matter) is defined is: if $v\in T_pM$ is tangent to the curve $c$ in $M$, then $\varphi_*v$ is tangent to the curve $\varphi\circ c$ (you can show that this is well-defined and that it's a linear transformation at each point $p$ between $T_pM$ and $T_{\varphi(p)}\mathbb{R}^n$). Well but $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)_p$ really is just notation for the vector tangent to the curve $c:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to M$ given in coordinates by
$$(\varphi\circ c)(t)=\varphi(p)+(0,\ldots,0,t,0,\ldots,0)$$
where the $t$ is in the $i$-th coordinate, and this curve is obviously tangent to $e_i=(0,\ldots,0,1,0\ldots,0)$. So $\varphi_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)_p=e_i$ and therefore

$$\varphi_*v=\varphi_*\left(\sum_{i=1}^ny^i(p,v)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)_p\right)=\sum_{i=1}^ny^i(p,v)\varphi_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)_p=\sum_{i=1}^ny^i(p,v)e_i=(y_1(p,v),\ldots,y_n(p,v))$$

This shows that I was correct. To show that you were also correct, given all of this, is not hard:

$$v(x_i)=\left(\sum_{i=j}^ny^j(p,v)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)_p\right)(x_i)=\sum_{i=j}^ny^j(p,v)\left(\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^j}\right)_p=\sum_{i=j}^ny^j(p,v)\delta^i_j=y_i(p,v)$$

Comment: I'm sorry if my questions are very primitive, I'm not yet really used to the notations and conventions which are typical for differential geometry...now in my definition, I regard $y^i$ as a function from $T_pM$ to $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $y^i(v)=v^i=v(x^i)$ right ? Whereas in your definition the $y^i$ are defined for each $v$ differently right?

Comment: No, they're all the same thing. What makes you think it's different?

Comment: No I meant that in your definition $y^i$ is not a function right?

Comment: Just to give an example why I have trouble understanding what $y^i$ is, we have a term like $\sum\limits_{i,j,k=1}^n \Gamma^k_{ij} y^iy^j \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_k}$ in an exercise, now I don't understand how  $\Gamma^k_{ij} y^iy^j \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_k}$ is defined..

Comment: It's also a function in my definition. You can think of it as a function $T_pM\to \mathbb{R}$ at each point $p\in U$ (where $U$ is your coordinate neighborhood). Now, of course that, if I fix a specific vector $v\in T_pM$ then $y^i(v)$ is really just a number, that I write as just $y^i$, which is abuse of notation.

Comment: I don't know if this is what's troubling you, but it'd be totally understandable. I'll edit the answer accordingly, just in case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93967/discussion-between-user1-and-paulo-mourao).